# I don't know how to format my FROM statement to avoid syntax error string literal

Tags: sql, string, syntax

I don't know why SQL isn't recognizing the table names in the `FROM` statements. It returns a syntax error saying expected string literal "peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders.Orders" at [7:10] I have tried to put double quotes in the FROM statement but to no avail. EDITED: I have added pictures of the details from both tables that I used. I have also tried using the detailed table name and get the same not found in the US error. See pictures please.

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    CONCAT(Warehouse.state, ":", Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM 'peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders.Orders' Orders) AS total_orders,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) <= 0.20
            THEN "fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
        WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) > 0.20
             AND COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) <= 0.60
            THEN "Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
        ELSE "Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders"
    END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM  
    'peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders.Warehouse' Warehouse
LEFT JOIN 
    warehouse_orders.Orders Orders ON Orders.warehouse_id = Warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    warehouse_name
HAVING
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0
```

[With FROM statements that have short table names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3pB.png)

[Warehouse table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWFpK.png)

[Orders Table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS0fi.png)

[With FROM statements with backticks and full table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMVyx.png)

Comment: try with back ticks (\`):

\`peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders\`.\`Warehouse\` 

or 

\`peak-bit-402819\`.\`warehouse_orders.Warehouse\` 

depending on whether `peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders` or `peak-bit-402819` is your database name

Comment: Please see new pictures. I tried editing the full table name with backticks, shows same error. I added pictures of the table names from both tables and the two pictures with same error with ticks and without.

Comment: Use `[peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders].[Warehouse]` (square-brackets) or `"peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders"."Warehouse"` (double-quotes) - not single-quotes - also note that the `.` is _not_ enclosed in brackes/quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If those are actual table names, you could try using brackets instead:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM [peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders.Orders] Orders) AS total_orders,
```

and

```
FROM  
    [peak-bit-402819.warehouse_orders.Warehouse] Warehouse
```